# Fade out/in sperate divs with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I saw a flash website and was curious to now if this is something possible to build using Jquery, obviously not the entire thing. I was more looking to fade out div1 and div2 with a button click.
This is the example site:
www.justinfarrellyconstruction.com

Example:
If i come to the homepage and click the portfolio button the Gallery Div will fade out then fade in another image. At the same time the Text div will fade out its content and load the portfolio text.

My apologies if this does not make sense, this is all quite new to me and im trying got learn.

Comment: Well, the answer is yes. I doubt anybody here is going to write the whole thing for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but hopefully this example will get you started in the right direction: http://jsfiddle.net/3mJ3z/

Basically, there are 3 menu items, and 3 corresponding content items. When you click the menu item, all the other content items disappears and the corresponding content item fades in. The HTML:

```
<div class="item-1 content-item">
    I am the content for item 1
</div>

<div class="item-2 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 2
</div>

<div class="item-3 content-item" style="display: none;">
    I am the content for item 3
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="2">Item 1</li>
    <li class="change-item" data-item="3">Item 1</li>
</ul>
​
```

The JS:

```
$('.change-item').click(function(){
    var this_item = $(this).attr("data-item");
    $('.content-item').hide();
    $('.item-' + this_item).fadeIn();
});​
```

Comment: Hi Eskimo, thanks for your response. I apologize if my question is vague. I really doubt anybody here is going to write the entire thing for me as well and I would not want them to. I am new to Jquery and just trying to figure out how this can be accomplished. I achieve the first part which is having the text div swapped out. Now just trying to figure out how to swap out the image div once the "Data item 2" button is clicked. Maybe im not wording it correctly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Eskimo,So i piggy backed your example to show you what I am trying to do. Im sure the code is wrong but from the example you can see what I am trying to accomplish but with the code done correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/3mJ3z/17/