# How to fade in div if other div was scrolled out

Tags: javascript, html, fade

The topic says it all.

Just fiddling about a one-page layout. The first section of the page shows an image within a div. If the logo was scrolled out of the visible area, another div with a smaller logo image should appear in the navbar. Of course the small logo should disappear if the big logo has been scrolled in again.

How to do that in js?

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: Javascript isn't my thing. I tried a bit but just got my whole js stuck. I asked google with no useful results (because having not the right search terms).

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this?

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('#element').visible(true)) {
          // show big logo
        } else {
          // show small logo
        }
   });
```

Comment: Nice quess, but I'd rather looking for something like this (but in js not in vb ;-) ):

if divWithBigImage.visible=false then divWithSmallImage.visible=true

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
// Document ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // When window is resized
    jQuery(window).bind("resize", function(){

        // If big logo does not fit in container
        if (jQuery("#big").width() >= jQuery("#container").width()) {

            // Big out, small in
            jQuery("#big").fadeOut(function(){
                jQuery("#small").fadeIn();
            });

        // If big logo fits in container
        } else {

            // Small out, big in
            jQuery("#small").fadeOut(function(){
                jQuery("#big").fadeIn();
            });

        }

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="big" src="big.png" alt="big" />
    <img id="small" src="small.png" alt="small" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, this will cause having only one of the logo which was chosen depending on the browser-window size as the page has been loaded.

It's really hard to explain for me...
Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942811/fade-out-in-sperate-divs-with-button-click) is an answer how to fade in/out a div on button click. My trigger should be the disappearing of an element instead a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jQuery Waypoints at all? http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

I think you are trying to do do something like the sticky menu example http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/ should be pretty easy to change to meet your needs.